# Проверка числа положительное/нет

Tags: javascript

Как на `Javascript` проверить положительное ли число и возвратить обратное?

Пример, передаю в функцию или ввожу в prompt:

1: -1
14: -14

**UPD:** код оказался с ошибкой, - плюс поменял на минус теперь меняет как нужно

```js
    function opposite(number) {
      if (number < 0) {
        return -(number)
      } else {
        return +(number)
      }
    }
    
    console.log(opposite(-1));
```

Comment: Умножте число на `-1`, получите обратное.

Comment: @PavelMayorov  за что минус?

Comment: А зачем вообще if если можно return 0-number;?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов хороший вопрос. зачем. я решил задачу как мог, потом попросил помощи у сообщества, с целью чтобы более опытные товарищи предложили более простое и универсальное решение

Comment: @stas0k ну вот оно и более простое :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function opposite(number) {
  if (number < 0) {
    return Math.abs(number)
  } else {
    return -Math.abs(number)
  }
}

opposite(700) //output -700
```

Для справки: [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)

Comment: Зачем так сложно-то?

Comment: @PavelMayorov это задание с сайта https://www.codewars.com/kata/56dec885c54a926dcd001095 - поэтому исходные данные такие

Answer (score 4):

```
function opposite(number) {
    return number * (-1);
}

opposite(-1) //output 1
```

Comment: отметьте ваш ответ как принятый и получите знак 'Самоучка' :)